# Admin uploaded user profile picture do not show up in search results but do on mysite

Tags: user-profile-service

When a user uploads their own picture it correctly shows both on their my site and in the search results but when admin uploads the user profile picture it does display on the users profile page but does not show in search result (placeholder picture is shown).

We have AD user 'meeting rooms' and want to upload the room picture via the admin but they don't display in the search results which is where it is needed.

Comment: Are the meeting room an ordinary AD users? Normally meeting rooms etc are created as Exchange ressource objects, that cannot be synchronized as users in user profile (there is no person object in AD)

Comment: Yes they are AD users. In AD users and computers the object type is 'user'.

Comment: I am not sure this is normal procedure to create ressources as "real" users in AD? Normally they are just created as a "mailbox" in Exchange. Could you try and have admin update a "normal" user to see if you can reproduce or if it is because these users are not entirely "normal" as they are used as ressources?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. This morning after running the full-crawl job over night I'm please to see the profile picture appearing in the search results. I did not run the Update-SPProfilePhotoStore command.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that this question can be closed? If it is just a problem specific to your environment that resolved itself, then it is probably not useful to other users of the site and we should just close it.

Answer (score -1):

Try pushing the updates of the photos using

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 -MySiteHostLocation <mySiteHostURL>
```

Eventually run search full-crawl or pushing profile changes (User Profile to SharePoint full syncronisation job)?

Comment: This is not related to question. The cmdlet checks for images synchronized from from ThumbnailPhoto binary octet string in AD (they are put in User Photos root directory with a guid name) and generate 3 thumbnails. The UI will automatically generate 3 thumbnails from the image user is uploading.